Fixed Points of two dimensional non-linear recurrence relations
I am trying to solve the following non-linear, 2-d, recurrence relations for my research. Specifically, I am hoping to find the fix points and limits. They are:
\begin{equation}
x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{2(2x_n-1)y_n^2}{1+(2x_n - 1)^2},
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
y_{n+1} = y_n \sqrt{1 + (2x_n - 1)^2}.
\end{equation}
I additionally have that $0 \leq x_0 \leq 1~\forall ~n$ and $-1 \leq y_0 \leq 1~\forall ~n$.
From here, I have founded the fix-points by setting
\begin{equation}
x_{n+1} = x_n, ~ ~ y_{n+1} = y_{n},
\end{equation}
which gives fixed points at $x = 1/2$ and $y=0$.
I can see that for any initial $x_0$ that $x_{n}$ converges to $1/2$. I can also see from the function for $y_{n+1}$ that it does not converge to $0$, but, that it does converge. This is given that as $x \rightarrow 1/2$, $y_{n+1} \rightarrow y_n$.
Is there a way to find what value $y_n$ converges to that depends on the initial conditions, $x_0, y_0$?

How well do you know differential calculus? If you are skilled enough, you could try to study a convenient smooth function of two variables. I haven’t made the computation but this should help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_mapping
